# My xor encryption not working on complex files

Tags: java, encryption, xor

Just for fun I have been trying to make a file encryptor which does a bitwise xor encryption against a 128-bit key. It seems to work for plain text files using some editors, but for others and more complex files I encounter a "corrupted file" error. If I do the encryption on a text file twice, in Gedit it displays the contents of the original file like it should, but in Notepad, I just get a whole bunch of question marks.

I have written this code in Java, however the encryption part is pretty universal. The key is in the form of an array of 8 16-bit characters:

```
char[] key = {26372, 15219, 53931, 50406, 26072, 23469, 25002, 37812};
```

To encrypt the file, I have a loop which runs this code:

```
builder.append((char)(bR.read() ^ key[pos++]));
if(pos == 8) pos = 0; //returns to first position in key
```

This reads the next character from the file using a BufferedReader, xors it against the next character in the key and appends it to a StringBuilder.

Here is the entire code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;


public class Encryptor implements Runnable {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Encryptor());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    JFrame frame;
    JButton bCancel, bEncrypt;
    JTextArea statusArea;
    JScrollPane statusScroll;
    JProgressBar progressBar;
    String fileContents, fileType, fileName;
    EncryptSwingWorker encryptWorker;
    char[] key = {
        26372, 15219, 53931, 50406, 26072, 23469, 25002, 37812};

    public void run() {

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch(Exception e) {}

        frame = new JFrame();

        statusArea = new JTextArea();
        statusArea.setEditable(false);
        statusScroll = new JScrollPane(statusArea);
        progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setValue(0);

        bCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        bCancel.setEnabled(false);
        bCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                        "Are you sure you want to cancel?",
                        "Warning", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                        null, null
                );
                if(option == 0) {
                    encryptWorker.cancel(true);
                    statusArea.append("Encryption cancelled\n");
                    progressBar.setValue(0);
                    progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                    bCancel.setEnabled(false);
                    bEncrypt.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }

        });
        bEncrypt = new JButton("Encrypt file...");
        bEncrypt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                encryptWorker = Encryptor.this.new EncryptSwingWorker();
                encryptWorker.execute();
            }

        });

        JPanel top = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        top.add(bEncrypt, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        top.add(bCancel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.getContentPane().add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(statusScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(progressBar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setSize(200, 150);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setTitle("sEncryptor");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("encryptor.png"));
    }

    void encrypt() throws IOException {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frame);

        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            if(fc.getSelectedFile() == null) {
                JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                    "You did not select a file",
                    "File Open Error",
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null,
                    null, null
                );
                encrypt();
                return;
            }

            bCancel.setEnabled(true);
            bEncrypt.setEnabled(false);

            fileName = fc.getSelectedFile().getPath();

            statusArea.append("Calculating size...\n");
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            int size = (int)(new File(fileName).length() / 32);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressBar.setMaximum(size);

            BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fc.getSelectedFile()));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            statusArea.append("Encrypting...\n");
            int pos = 0;
            for(double d = 0; bR.ready(); d += 0.03125) {
                if(encryptWorker.isCancelled()) return;
                progressBar.setValue((int)d);
                builder.append((char)(bR.read() ^ key[pos++]));
                if(pos == 8) pos = 0;
            }

            progressBar.setValue(0);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

            fileContents = builder.toString();
            bR.close();
            statusArea.append("Encryption finished\n");
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        }
    }

    void save(String file) throws IOException {
        statusArea.append("Saving...\n");
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        BufferedWriter bW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        bW.write(fileContents);
        bW.close();
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        statusArea.append("Done!\n");
    }

    void saveAs() throws IOException {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        int returnVal = fc.showSaveDialog(frame);

        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            if(fc.getSelectedFile() == null) {
                JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                    "You did not select a file",
                    "File Open Error",
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null,
                    null, null
                );
                saveAs();
                return;
            }

            save(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath());
        }
    }

    class EncryptSwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            encrypt();
            if(EncryptSwingWorker.this.isCancelled()) return null;
            bCancel.setEnabled(false);
            while(true) {
                Object[] options = {"Override", "Save As...", "Cancel"};
                int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                        "Override existing file?",
                        "Save", JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                        options, options[0]
                );
                if(option == 0)
                    try {
                        save(fileName);
                    } catch(IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                else if(option == 1)
                    try {
                        saveAs();
                    } catch(IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                else {
                    int option1 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                            "The encryption will be lost if you continue\n" +
                            "Are you sure you want to cancel?",
                            "Warning", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                            null, null
                    );
                    if(option1 == 1) continue;
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            fileContents = "";
            bEncrypt.setEnabled(true);
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing in my code, or does xoring the entire file cause problems?

Comment: Could you *please* only include the minimal, actually relevant code that can be proven to fail?

Comment: Holy cow, that's a lot of uncommented code. Consider posting it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. That said, I ran it on a file, it created a new file _full_ of `3F` (63 in decimal) characters. You might try to debug it, go step by step, and check your logic.

Comment: From trying to read the source code, here's something for you as a recommendation for future self-improving - [enums](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20enum)! So much less error prone, so much more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Got it. The problem is in the file encoding, as always :). Never, *ever*, depend on default encoding - it will eventually backfire at you.

Since `Reader` and `Writer` classes are made for plaintext inputs/outputs, it gets messed up. In this case, the `Writer` doesn't know what to do with the various integer numbers it gets and ends up failing. When you fix the `Writer`, you must fix the `Reader`, too, because the encrypted data may not by only valid characters...

The **best** solution is to ignore characters, use bytes and [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html), [`FileOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) (wrapped by their `Buffered` brothers if necessary), because those are made to handle binary data. That way, you'll end up reading/writing exactly the data you intend to read/write. Try to hack it together yourself, it's a great lesson. If you'll get stuck hard, look [here](http://pastebin.com/NuXJQhAN).

The **easiest** solution is to change only two lines. Note that it will, again, only work for text files! Seriously, don't mess random numbers and printable chars together.

```
BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fc.getSelectedFile()));
```

to

```
BufferedReader bR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fc.getSelectedFile()), "UTF-8"));
```

and

```
BufferedWriter bW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
```

to

```
BufferedWriter bW = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Just to add: In short, use bare stream in Java for binary data, use reader/writer (with proper encoding) for text.

Comment: Absolutely true, I embedded it into the answer.